# FLEX data manipulation separating data for bargraph display from a PHP call

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I am a novice FLEX Developer I want to separate the data from the PHP call to Different CollectionArrays So that I can use the data for a bar-graph;

I created a static version of the bar-graph and separated the Collection array manually I don't want this done manually I need to do it dynamically. So what I am trying to understand is where to put the event-listener how to add to a collectionArray then once the collection array(s) are built. use that information to build the bar graphs...

```
    /*
         *
        36, > 2 years, Compliance
        6, 0-90 Days, Compliance
        32, 181-365 Days, Compliance
        72, 366-730 Days, Compliance
        15, 91-180 Days, Compliance
        4, > 2 years, Medium/Low
        118, 0-90 Days, Medium/Low
        143, 181-365 Days, Medium/Low
        29, 366-730 Days, Medium/Low
        67, 91-180 Days, Medium/Low
        10, > 2 years, Patient Safety
        2, 0-90 Days, Patient Safety
        17, 181-365 Days, Patient Safety
        18, 366-730 Days, Patient Safety
        5, 91-180 Days, Patient Safety 
        */
```

I need the above information 
translated to the bottom information
using a onload finished event listener.

```
        [Bindable]
        public var _compliance:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {Count:36, Time : "> 2 years"       },
            {Count:6,  Time : "0-90 Days"       },
            {Count:32, Time : "181-365 Days"    },
            {Count:72, Time : "366-730 Days"    },
            {Count:15, Time : "91-180 Days"     }
        ]);

        [Bindable]
        public var _medlow:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {Count:4,   Time : "> 2 years"      },
            {Count:118, Time : "0-90 Days"      },
            {Count:143, Time : "181-365 Days"   },
            {Count:29,  Time : "366-730 Days"   },
            {Count:67,  Time : "91-180 Days"    }
        ]);;

        [Bindable]
        public var _patient:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {Count:10, Time : "> 2 years"       },
            {Count:2,  Time : "0-90 Days"       },
            {Count:17, Time : "181-365 Days"    },
            {Count:18, Time : "366-730 Days"    },
            {Count:5,  Time : "91-180 Days"     }
        ]);;
```

Comment: So, the data is coming from PHP in a straight string? No JSON? XML? Nothing?

Comment: Nice no actually it is coming in as an ArrayCollection.

Comment: ...so you're using AMF with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @J_A_X said, data like this makes things a bit more difficult because it becomes your job to parse it.  But, no biggie.  You can just do some `split` work to do the parsing here.  Assuming your lines are delimited with "\n", then the following should work.  I am using [ActionLinq](http://ActionLinq.org) which makes data processing a breeze.

I am assuming your data from the server has been put in a string called `serverData`:

```
private function parseLine(line:String):Object {
    var split:Array = line.split(", ");
    return { Count: Number(split[0]), Time: split[1], Category: split[2] };
}

private function getDataBy(category:String):ArrayCollection {
    return Enumerable.from(serverData.split("\n"))
            .select(parseLine)
            .where(function(x:*):Boolean { return x.Category == category })
            .toArrayCollection();
}

[Bindable] public var _compliance:ArrayCollection;
[Bindable] public var _medlow:ArrayCollection;
[Bindable] public var _patient:ArrayCollection;
```

Then, when you get your data back from the server, you can populate your `ArrayCollection`s:

```
_compliance = getDataBy("Compliance");
_medlow = getDataBy("Medium/Low");
_patient = getDataBy("Patient Safety");
```

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify that it is an ArrayCollection I was parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brian 
I like yours way better then my solution as its smaller and reusable
 getAllItemsResult is the data set from the call to the server.

```
    public function setData():void{

        var t_com:Object = new Object();
        var t_med:Object = new Object();
        var t_pat:Object = new Object();

            for (var i:Object in getAllItemsResult.lastResult)
            {
                var n:Object = getAllItemsResult.lastResult[i];
                var t:Object = new Object();

                switch(n['Priority']){
                    case 'Compliance':
                        t = {
                                'Count' : getAllItemsResult.lastResult[i]['THECOUNT'],
                                'Time': getAllItemsResult.lastResult[i]['CAPA_AGE']
                            }
                        t_com.addItem(t);
                    break;
                    case 'Medium/Low':
                        t = {
                                'Count' : getAllItemsResult.lastResult[i]['THECOUNT'],
                                'Time': getAllItemsResult.lastResult[i]['CAPA_AGE']
                            }
                        t_med.addItem(t);                           
                    break;
                    case 'Patient Safety':
                        t = {
                                'Count' : getAllItemsResult.lastResult[i]['THECOUNT'],
                                'Time': getAllItemsResult.lastResult[i]['CAPA_AGE']
                            }
                        t_pat.addItem(t);
                    break;
                    default:
                    break;
                }

            }

            var sortArr:Array = new Array("0-90 Days","91-180 Days","181-365 Days","366-730 Days","> 2 years");
            //loop through array then add items to occording to array length

        }


    ]]>
```

now I got to figure out how to sort the darn thing!